# Creating an API with svelte@next

Tags: javascript, node.js, svelte-3

Starting a new small application I decided to go with the new svelte@next.
I like it with it's hot reload using snowpack.
But I have had problems creating an API method like with Sapper. Here is my code example:

```js
export function get(req, res) {
  res.end('Hello');
}
```

It get the request (req) but res.end has error 'end' is not defined.
After logging the res object itself, I realised that it was empty.

Comment: As of today svelte@next is in like pre-pre-alpha, any answer to this question can be wrong by tomorrow.

Comment: but there might be a right one today :-)